# error obtaining vcs status when running delve as root

Tags: git, go, debugging, delve

I am trying to run `sudo dlv debug` on Arch Linux and I keep getting following error:

```
error obtaining VCS status: exit status 128
    Use -buildvcs=false to disable VCS stamping.
exit status 1
```

When I remove the .git folder, `sudo dlv debug` runs as expected, so I assume it could be a configuration issue with git?!

Comment: In some cases, the best solution will be: Don't run as root.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had a similar error message when debugging code opened in a remote container via vscode.

when I used `git status` I got a message saying the git repository is unsafe was owned by someone else. And then a message explaining to use:

```
git config --global --add safe.directory [your dir here]
```

doing this I no longer get the VCS stamping warning

Comment: I have the same issue and this answer helped me to understand what is wrong with it, so I have set proper user access to the files.

Comment: Same issue while building Terraform providers, this helped

Comment: Make sure the dir does not have symlinks in it. This works only with absolute paths.

Comment: This solved this error for me. But my case was different. I had set the container USER to "app", but my volume mount was set to "root". So I guess Git didn't trust because the owner of the directory was different from the current login user.

Answer (score 0):

For those coming from Google, you probably don't have the permissions to a folder. `chmod user:user folder` and add `-R` to propagate it in subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

This problem also occurs when Go is used with a very old version of Git, such as version 1.8, which is a part of CentOS 7. Reinstalling Git version 2.36 resolves the issue.